# Subordinate had conversations with my boss- should I have been told?

Tags: professionalism, management, career-development, conflict

I am a C level manager whose direct report, a senior manager, went to my boss to complain I was over managing him. Through several meetings it was determined my report was at fault for not taking charge and thus forcing me to periodically interject my direction at a level of detail I shouldn't given my position. I recently learned of this when I was defending his slowness in acting to my boss. These meetings happened months ago.

Should I have expected to have this revealed to me when it happened?

Comment: Unless I misread, the determination that your report was at fault was done without going you involved. What's wrong with that? If the determination were going the other way, your superior might/should have wanted to hear your side of the story as a matter of due diligence and basic fairness.

Comment: Should you have been told or not is not the sort of question that works well here.  Consider asking how you  should go about avoiding this from happening in the future or something similar that provides a constructive response rather than asking fro a subjective judgement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in my mind that is unusual.  I'm also a C level manager and would be concerned if this happened to me.  One meeting?  No problem.  Several meetings?   I would be annoyed that my boss did not bring me into the coversation.  As Joe says in his comments, your next course of action depends upon your relationship with your boss, but I don't think it would be out of line to express your concern.

Be sure to do this in a way that gets across that you want to help, and not as a whine.  e.g. "I'm concerned that my report didn't feel that he/she could approach me with this, and give me an opportunity to correct the problem, before bringing it to you.   What can I do to avoid this in the future?"

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure how much difference it makes at C-level, but in general it's not a good idea to *always* tell someone if a complaint has been made about them. Why? Because reports will stop making complaints about their boss, whether or not the boss deserves them. There needs to be the opportunity of giving feedback without repercussions, or there will be no feedback. Obviously you should be given the chance to defend yourself if there was any thought that you might have done something wrong, but since they determined you hadn't even without your input that wasn't necessary.

In this particular case, since there was no action you needed to take, it's not clear to me how you knowing what was said would benefit you. In fact the only likely result was to make you dislike your report more, which doesn't help anyone.

If it were me I would be happy that the company handled this properly and exonerated me without the need for me to defend myself.

There is an issue that your report felt unable to approach you directly. But that's separate from whether you should have been told about the complaint.